# How to Fill null with next non-null value in SQL..?

Tags: sql

I want to fill null values with next non-null value, sharing what I was able to achieve.

This is what I have using the code below.

```
WITH RECURSIVE ALL_DATES_BETWEEN AS (
    SELECT '2023-11-01' AS ALL_DATES
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATE_ADD(ALL_DATES, INTERVAL 1 DAY) FROM ALL_DATES_BETWEEN
    WHERE ALL_DATES<'2023-11-30'
),

GET_DATE AS (
SELECT *, 
    DAYNAME(ALL_DATES) AS WEEK_NUMBER,
    WEEK(ALL_DATES) AS WEEK_NUM,
    CASE WHEN DAYNAME(ALL_DATES)='Thursday' THEN ALL_DATES ELSE NULL END AS WEEK_STARTING
FROM ALL_DATES_BETWEEN)


SELECT *, FIRST_VALUE(WEEK_STARTING IGNORE NULLS) OVER (ORDER BY ALL_DATES
    ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND
    UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)  FROM GET_DATE
```

Output of code above

```
+------------+-------------+---------------+
| ALL_DATES  | WEEK_NUMBER | WEEK_STARTING |
+------------+-------------+---------------+
| 2023-11-16 | Thursday    | 2023-11-16    |
| 2023-11-17 | Friday      | NULL          |
| 2023-11-18 | Saturday    | NULL          |
| 2023-11-19 | Sunday      | NULL          |
| 2023-11-20 | Monday      | NULL          |
| 2023-11-21 | Tuesday     | NULL          |
| 2023-11-22 | Wednesday   | NULL          |
| 2023-11-23 | Thursday    | 2023-11-23    |
| 2023-11-24 | Friday      | NULL          |
| 2023-11-25 | Saturday    | NULL          |
| 2023-11-26 | Sunday      | NULL          |
| 2023-11-27 | Monday      | NULL          |
| 2023-11-28 | Tuesday     | NULL          |
| 2023-11-29 | Wednesday   | NULL          |
| 2023-11-30 | Thursday    | 2023-11-30    |
+------------+-------------+---------------+
```

I want to start my week on Thursday and end on Wednesday, Was just wondering is there a windows function to fill NULL with next Non-Null Value.

```
+------------+-------------+---------------+
| ALL_DATES  | WEEK_NUMBER | WEEK_STARTING |
+------------+-------------+---------------+
| 2023-11-16 | Thursday    | 2023-11-16    |
| 2023-11-17 | Friday      | 2023-11-16    |
| 2023-11-18 | Saturday    | 2023-11-16    |
| 2023-11-19 | Sunday      | 2023-11-16    |
| 2023-11-20 | Monday      | 2023-11-16    |
| 2023-11-21 | Tuesday     | 2023-11-16    |
| 2023-11-22 | Wednesday   | 2023-11-16    |
| 2023-11-23 | Thursday    | 2023-11-23    |
| 2023-11-24 | Friday      | 2023-11-23    |
| 2023-11-25 | Saturday    | 2023-11-23    |
| 2023-11-26 | Sunday      | 2023-11-23    |
| 2023-11-27 | Monday      | 2023-11-23    |
| 2023-11-28 | Tuesday     | 2023-11-23    |
| 2023-11-29 | Wednesday   | 2023-11-23    |
| 2023-11-30 | Thursday    | 2023-11-30    |
+------------+-------------+---------------+
```

How can I achieve this in SQL

Below is the SQL code I used to generate the date table. I tried using `FIRST_VALUE` but wasn't able to successfully use it.

Requirement - I wanted to have separate column for week start date, so that I group by custom week start date, will create similar column for week end date, Any help would be super helpful.

Comment: Mysql and sql server are two different database products with different implementations of sql. Removed the conflicting product tags. Please add the ine back that you actually use!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I was able to figure out an answer as well.

```
WITH RECURSIVE ALL_DATES_BETWEEN AS (
    SELECT '2023-10-29' AS ALL_DATES
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATE_ADD(ALL_DATES, INTERVAL 1 DAY) FROM ALL_DATES_BETWEEN
    WHERE ALL_DATES<'2023-11-30'
),

GET_DATE AS (
SELECT *, 
    DAYNAME(ALL_DATES) AS WEEK_NUMBER,
    -- WEEK(ALL_DATES) AS WEEK_NUM,
    LAG(WEEK(ALL_DATES),4) OVER(ORDER BY ALL_DATES) AS CUSTOM_WEEK,
    CASE WHEN DAYNAME(ALL_DATES)='Thursday' THEN ALL_DATES ELSE NULL END AS WEEK_STARTING
FROM ALL_DATES_BETWEEN)


SELECT *, MIN(WEEK_STARTING) OVER (PARTITION BY CUSTOM_WEEK) AS CUSTOM_WEEK_START
 FROM GET_DATE
ORDER BY 1
```

Above query will give

```
+------------+-------------+-------------+---------------+-------------------+
| ALL_DATES  | WEEK_NUMBER | CUSTOM_WEEK | WEEK_STARTING | CUSTOM_WEEK_START |
+------------+-------------+-------------+---------------+-------------------+
| 2023-10-29 | Sunday      |        NULL | NULL          | NULL              |
| 2023-10-30 | Monday      |        NULL | NULL          | NULL              |
| 2023-10-31 | Tuesday     |        NULL | NULL          | NULL              |
| 2023-11-01 | Wednesday   |        NULL | NULL          | NULL              |
| 2023-11-02 | Thursday    |          44 | 2023-11-02    | 2023-11-02        |
| 2023-11-03 | Friday      |          44 | NULL          | 2023-11-02        |
| 2023-11-04 | Saturday    |          44 | NULL          | 2023-11-02        |
| 2023-11-05 | Sunday      |          44 | NULL          | 2023-11-02        |
| 2023-11-06 | Monday      |          44 | NULL          | 2023-11-02        |
| 2023-11-07 | Tuesday     |          44 | NULL          | 2023-11-02        |
| 2023-11-08 | Wednesday   |          44 | NULL          | 2023-11-02        |
| 2023-11-09 | Thursday    |          45 | 2023-11-09    | 2023-11-09        |
| 2023-11-10 | Friday      |          45 | NULL          | 2023-11-09        |
| 2023-11-11 | Saturday    |          45 | NULL          | 2023-11-09        |
| 2023-11-12 | Sunday      |          45 | NULL          | 2023-11-09        |
| 2023-11-13 | Monday      |          45 | NULL          | 2023-11-09        |
| 2023-11-14 | Tuesday     |          45 | NULL          | 2023-11-09        |
| 2023-11-15 | Wednesday   |          45 | NULL          | 2023-11-09        |
| 2023-11-16 | Thursday    |          46 | 2023-11-16    | 2023-11-16        |
| 2023-11-17 | Friday      |          46 | NULL          | 2023-11-16        |
| 2023-11-18 | Saturday    |          46 | NULL          | 2023-11-16        |
| 2023-11-19 | Sunday      |          46 | NULL          | 2023-11-16        |
| 2023-11-20 | Monday      |          46 | NULL          | 2023-11-16        |
| 2023-11-21 | Tuesday     |          46 | NULL          | 2023-11-16        |
| 2023-11-22 | Wednesday   |          46 | NULL          | 2023-11-16        |
| 2023-11-23 | Thursday    |          47 | 2023-11-23    | 2023-11-23        |
| 2023-11-24 | Friday      |          47 | NULL          | 2023-11-23        |
| 2023-11-25 | Saturday    |          47 | NULL          | 2023-11-23        |
| 2023-11-26 | Sunday      |          47 | NULL          | 2023-11-23        |
| 2023-11-27 | Monday      |          47 | NULL          | 2023-11-23        |
| 2023-11-28 | Tuesday     |          47 | NULL          | 2023-11-23        |
| 2023-11-29 | Wednesday   |          47 | NULL          | 2023-11-23        |
| 2023-11-30 | Thursday    |          48 | 2023-11-30    | 2023-11-30        |
+------------+-------------+-------------+---------------+-------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach, heavily using analytic functions:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t.*,
           SUM(CASE WHEN WEEK_STARTING IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
               OVER (ORDER BY ALL_DATES) AS flag
    FROM yourTable t
)

SELECT ALL_DATES, WEEK_NUMBER,
       MAX(WEEK_STARTING) OVER (PARTITION BY flag) AS WEEK_STARTING
FROM cte
ORDER BY ALL_DATES;
```

Comment: Thank You @tim I think I followed the same logic, but used Week_number

Comment: @Priyansh The day of the week isn't too helpful here, as it is text and doesn't sort in any meaningful order.

Comment: do you think my answer is not correct, where do you think error is..?